# ios user registration fails when double pressed

Tags: php, ios, ios7

I am attempting a member registration in ios using php script to communicate with localhost mysql. Insertion and retrieval works well. I am trying now to protect against users with same email being able to register. This is what I did:

```
<?php 
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');


$db_conn = new  PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pal','root','root');
$db_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$message = "";
$email = ($_POST['email']); 

$qry = $db_conn->prepare('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = :email');
$qry->bindParam(':email', $email);
$qry->execute();
$result = $qry->fetchColumn();

//return $result;

echo utf8_encode($result);
?>
```

and in my viewcontroller, I did this:

```
-(IBAction)registrationBtn:(id)sender{
    NSString *email = self.emailField.text;
    NSString *password = self.passwordField.text;
    NSString *firstName = self.firstNameField.text;
    NSString *lastName = self.lastNameField.text;
    NSString *birthYear = self.yearField.text;
    /*String will contain Male/Femald */
    NSString *gender = [self.genderField titleForSegmentAtIndex:self.genderField.selectedSegmentIndex];

    if(email.length > 0 && password.length > 0 && firstName.length > 0 && lastName.length > 0 && birthYear.length > 0 && gender.length > 0)
    {

        BOOL userExist = [self checkIfUserExists:email];
        NSLog(@"Boolean Results:%hhd", userExist);
        if(userExist == false)
        {
            NSLog(@"User Doesn't Exist..Proceeding with Registration");
            /*All fields checked not empty, create raw string for HTTP*/
            NSString *rawStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@&password=%@&&firstname=%@&lastname=%@&birthyear=%@&gender=%@", email,
            password,
            firstName,
            lastName,
            birthYear,gender];

            NSData *data = [rawStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/registration.php"];
            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [request setHTTPBody:data];


            NSURLResponse *response;
            NSError *err;
            NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

            NSString *responseString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[responseData bytes]];
            NSLog(@"Response String: %@", responseString);

            NSString *success = @"success";
            [success dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; // Dismiss the viewController upon success
        }else{
            /*Issue error that user exists with this email*/
            NSLog(@"%s", "Error");
        }

    }

}
```

and the function being called checkIfUserExist is here too:

```
-(BOOL)checkIfUserExists:(NSString*)userEmail
{
    NSString *rawStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@", userEmail];
    NSData *data = [rawStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/checkUserExist.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:data];


    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *err;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

    NSString *responseString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[responseData bytes]];

    NSString *success = @"success";
    [success dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Check User Reponse String: %@", responseString);
    if([responseString isEqualToString:userEmail])
    {
        NSLog(@"Check User = True");
        return true;
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Check User = False");
        return false;
    }
}
```

I start the simulator with database table empty. I fill information in registration form and click button. Data is stored in database. Next time I click the button register again, it says it exists so can't create record (correct behaviour). Third time or so many number of click afterwards, it keeps adding and saying user doesn't exist.

I personally believe the problem to be that php response in checkIfUserExist function is not always returning a string of email from php script. it returns null sometime and sometimes empty and sometimes with email. When it returns with email, the operation goes as planned.

Please help.

As requested, database structure:

[image]

Comment: Can you show database structure?

Comment: Yes sure. Editing the question to reflect it.

Comment: If you want a user can register once in your system; Email column must be unique

Comment: I admit that skipped me but I was simply testing application. If that changes to unique, how can it solve the problem though (other than DB table integrity)?

Comment: Unique means you can not add same value more than once. I dont understand what do you mean with integrity

Comment: And if i were you, i will change all text structures to varchar in db table.

Comment: Ok how can I make it unique? The unique button next to it is disabled unlike some other columns. I agree and I will set them to good number of chars respectively

Comment: If you dont have any value on your table; simply delete column and re create it with varchar (264) unique

Comment: I am not familiar of ios or objective c; but in php side you can simply make a select query for email checking db first and add an if else statement "if exists return error user exists; else add user" something like that.

Comment: Aye thanks for the help so far. I will do recommended changes and wait for someone to help with ios part

Comment: Your welcomr. Did you change email column in your db and re try your app?

Comment: yes I just did...unfortunately same thing...but db is not having multiple entries anymore.

Comment: Okay. Good luck with ios part.

Comment: You should check the error returned from the connection, log the data as well as the string created from it, don't return the full email address, just use a simple flag (or http status code is even better) to indicate the status.